# How can I verify if user input only contains digits in C?

Tags: c, validation, scanf, fgets

I am writing code that prompts the user a numeric input.  If the input is nonnumeric, it loops back to the prompt. I am getting stuck trying to verify that the input contains ONLY numeric characters.  So far, my code seems to only check the first character of the input. For example:

545454 breaks from loop.
54545j breaks from loop.
asdfgh loops back to prompt.
a54545 loops back to prompt.

Any input containing a character should loop back to the prompt.

This is the loop I'm referring to:

```
    int a;
    int b;
    char buffer[100];
    long long ccnum;
    
    do
    {
        printf("Please input the credit card number: ");
        fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin );
    }
    while ( sscanf( buffer, "%lld", &ccnum) != 1 );
```

I am just trying to understand why it is not looping back to the prompt regardless of the location of the nonnumeric character in the input.  Am I at least on the right track to getting the verification I'm looking for?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to test the return value from `fgets()` so that you can spot EOF accurately.  The `scanf()` only checks that the start of the string is a decimal number.  You could see where the conversion stops using the `%n` conversion specifier, though that's a little convoluted.  Alternatively, write a function that uses `<ctype.h>` to check whether everything is numeric.  What do you want to do about leading and trailing white space, and sign characters?  Don't forget that `fgets()` includes the newline in the string if there's enough space for it.  (What are `a` and `b` doing in your code?)

Comment: You are trying to read in a credit card number as an integer. As soon as you actually achieve that, you will run into troubles with the next part of the assignment. From what I have seen in other questions here, you will later go back to using a character sequence later. So please double check that you are really required to read into an integer. Also have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem for a general insight on thinking obstacles while asking questions here and programming in general.

Comment: You could investigate `strspn()`. `strspn( "4545", "0123456789" )` returns `4` that is the length of the string... Combine this with the suggestion of `%n` from @JonathanLeffler, and you have a compound condition to suit your needs...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I will look into the functions <ctype.h> has for me to work with.  Fortunately, the problem set I’m working on specifically states to assume the user will input all numeric characters and ccnum will not contain leading zeroes.  When researching it, a numeric check did not seem too difficult to implement so I figured I’d give it a shot since I’m not doing this for a class or anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your test only checks that the input starts with a number, and it will accept initial white space and an optional sign, which should be invalid too.

You can use `sscanf()` for this, but with a different format:

- `%*[0-9]` reads and discards all digits (at least one), then
- `%n` sets the number of digits found into an `int` variable and
- `%1[\n]` reads exactly one newline.

If `sscanf()` returns `1`, then the newline has been found and `len` contains the number of digits found. If the return value is not `1`, the input is not entirely composed of digits or is en empty line.

Testing for `fgets()` failure is also required to detect and report the end of file.

Here is a modified version:

```
    char buffer[100];
    char eol[2];
    int len;
    
    for (;;) {
        printf("Please input the credit card number: ");
        if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) {
            printf("unexpected end of file\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%*[0-9]%n%1[\n]", &len, eol) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input: must only contain digits\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (len != 13 && len != 16) {
            printf("credit card number must have 13 or 16 digits\n");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
```

As suggested by *@Fe2O3*, instead of `sscanf()`, you can use `strspn()` from `<string.h>` to implement the same tests:

```
        // counts the number of digits at the beginning of buffer
        len = strspn(buffer, "0123456789");
        if (buffer[len] != '\n') {
            printf("invalid input: must only contain digits\n");
            continue;
        }
```